# Using the back button in an Android Webview (Crosswalk)

Tags: android, webview, android-studio-3.0

Developing an app with webview using crosswalk. Have overridden the back button for doubleback to exit.

Now the question is how to use the back button as well for back navigation on the webview.

Code snippets below

```
if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {

            //OneSignal Push Notification
            OneSignal.startInit(this)
                    .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                    .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                    .init();

            OSPermissionSubscriptionState status = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState();
            boolean isEnabled = status.getPermissionStatus().getEnabled();
            boolean isSubscribed = status.getSubscriptionStatus().getSubscribed();
            boolean subscriptionSetting = status.getSubscriptionStatus().getUserSubscriptionSetting();

            userID = status.getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId();
            loadUrl(launchUrl+"?playerid="+userID);
        }
```

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Again To Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you wanna navigate to previous activity from the. I am explaining solutions by numbering.

1). You can use a toolbar or Actionbar with back button.

[image: This image is showing you the way you can navigate between activities]

2) You can add Views in xml layout file of your activity

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ImageButton 
           android:id="@+id/ibBack"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_back_icon"
          android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/your_desired_value" />

      <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/ibBack" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

you can now initialize you views in your java/ kotlin file and can set listeners on them according to your requirement.